# References on collective intelligence with respect to CS applications

Tags: reference-request, education, software-engineering, books

In recent years the field of "collective intelligence" sometimes known as [Web 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0) has had a big impact on computer science, software engineering, and software development. Stackexchange software itself is a large scale evolving application or implementation and experiment along the lines of harnessing collective intelligence.

> What are some references especially with a CS angle on this connection between collective intelligence/Web 2.0 and CS?

Comment: This seems to be for the social sciences department, not CS.

Comment: @dave actually "collective intelligence" is much different than machine learning although there is some overlap. dont know what made you think they're synonyms. if either of you or anyone else just glanced at a TOC of any of the books cited, maybe youd figure it out. guess its just too cutting edge for this venue. _irony_ .. oh and more well-intentioned effort down in flames =(

Comment: Moderator notice: I've deleted several obsolete and off-topic comments. To vnz in particular: please [be nice](http://cs.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette).

Comment: uh huh ok fyi [defn of collective intelligence, wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_intelligence)

Comment: @raphael wrt social science in CS context ... tcs.se, [algorithmic lens in the social sciences](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6387/algorithmic-lens-in-the-social-sciences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Programming Collective Intelligence: Building Smart Web 2.0 Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596529325) by Segaran
- [Collective Intelligence in Action](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933988312) by Alag
- [Algorithms of the Intelligent Web](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933988665) by Marmanis and Babenko
- [Mining the Social Web: Analyzing Data from Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, and Other Social Media Sites](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449388345) by Russell
- [Building Web Reputation Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/059615979X) by Farmer & Glass

this area is also connected to "social applications"

- [Building Social Web Applications: Establishing Community at the Heart of Your Site](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596518757) by Bell
- [Designing Social Interfaces: Principles, Patterns, and Practices for Improving the User Experience (Animal Guide)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596154925) by Crumlish
- [Designing for the social web](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321534921) by Porter

Comment: This is a link collection, not an answer.

Comment: its a _compiled/curated list of references_, apparently also a _waste of time_ here

Comment: It's simply a consequence of [network-wide policy](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) which has a good reason: when links die (and they will) your answer contains nil content.

Comment: there is no such policy afaik nor could there be (agreed there is at times an informal "off-the-books" stigma/taboo). did you actually read what you just cited? it says exactly the _opposite_ of what you claimed. ***Links to external resources are encouraged***. moreover maybe you didnt notice but se automatically refmts amazon links to tie into their affiliate program

Comment: Don't stop reading when it suits you: "[...] but please **add context around the link** so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: yep! added the authors of the books as context. =) the question asked for refs so that part is self explanatory. but, maybe thats not good enough. so maybe just skip the hassle & delete this whole Q/A? there are only 3 upvotes so far and a single _"contributor"_ on the whole time consuming exercise, it cant hurt much right? (also the source of deleted comments relating to a long-ago disagreement...) just trying to help out & think like a _moderator_ here. its good the mods are specifically so _attentive_ to the weak content around here!